# Display Google reCAPTCHA response on same page

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I'm building a site with a contact form, I want to be able to display the Google reCAPTCHA response on the same page (e.g. "Message sent successfully" or "Invalid reCAPTCHA. Try again."), rather than it forwarding to my other .php file.

I have tried this via localhost and I'm able to get the responses via the other .php file just fine, but it takes you away from the homepage, which I don't want.

If I have the contact form code in the main website code, it does act how I want it, but I'd rather have two seperate files & do `<form action="assets/php/form.php" method="post">`.

I've tried [illustrating this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzfMs.jpg) via Paint (I'm no artist).

I'm kind of a novice, I done some basic HTML/CSS about 5/6 years back, but haven't really coded since.

Here is the code so far:

#### index.php (just the form)

```
<form action="assets/php/form.php" method="post">
    <div class="fields">
        <div class="field half">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="field half">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="My Site Key"></div>

<br/>

    <ul class="actions">
        <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" class="submit-btn"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

### form.php

```
<?php
    
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $mailTo = "email@mydomain.co.uk";
        $headers = "From: ".$email;
        $txt = "You have received an email from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;

        $secretKey = "My Secret Key";
        $responseKey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$responseKey";

        $response = file_get_contents($url);
        $response = json_decode($response);

        if ($response->success) {
            mail($mailTo, $email, $txt, $headers);
            header("Location: http://localhost/website/index.php?formsent");
            echo "Thanks for sending us a message, it was sent successfully. We will get back to you as soon as possible.";
        } 
        
        else {
            echo "Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.";
        }
        
    }
?>
```

Hopefully this is enough info for someone to help. Thanks.

Comment: just put the content of form.php at the beginning of the file index.php, and remove the attribute action of the form in the index.php file

Comment: @GiacomoM thanks for your help, I managed to get it working as intended. I got rid of the form action & added `<div class="captcha">
            <?php include 'assets/php/form.php';?>
           </div>` underneath the captcha & it works great. Thank you.